# jquery click-function is executed when page loads but not when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery to get the height of a div `#img-copyright` when the page is loaded, write in the `var copyrightHeight` and set the height of the div to 0.

When a different div is clicked, the `function showImgCopyright()` should set the max-height of the div #img-copyright to the content of the var.

I made two tries.

First one:

```
var copyrightHeight;

$(document).ready(function () {

    copyrightHeight = $("#img-copyright").height();

    console.log(copyrightHeight);
    // just used to see if the height got written in the var - it is

    $("img-copyright").css("max-height", 0);

    $("#show-img-copyright").click(showImgCopyright());

    function showImgCopyright() {
        $("#img-copyright").css("max-height", copyrightHeight);
    }


});
```

Second one:

```
var copyrightHeight;

$(document).ready(function () {

    copyrightHeight = $("#img-copyright").height();

    console.log(copyrightHeight);
    // just used to see if the height got written in the var - it is

    $("img-copyright").css("max-height", 0);

    $("#show-img-copyright").click(function (){
        $("#img-copyright").css("max-height", copyrightHeight);
    });


});
```

In the first example the function is directly executed after the page is loaded and NOT when clicking the div (not the way I wanted it to be).
In the second example it works as I wanted it - the function just is executed when clicking the div.
But I don't get why.

How can I make it work with an extra function like in the first example?

Comment: When passing a named function to an event handler, you want to leave out the parenthesis, so `click(showImgCopyright());` should be `click(showImgCopyright);`. By attaching the parenthesis, you are really just running the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

I also found out, I forgot a # in the line  `$("img-copyright").css("max-height", 0);`.

So the right code would be:

```
var copyrightHeight;

$(document).ready(function () {

    copyrightHeight = $("#img-copyright").height();

    $("#img-copyright").css("max-height", 0);

    $("#show-img-copyright").click(showImgCopyright);

    function showImgCopyright() {
        $("#img-copyright").css("max-height", copyrightHeight);
    }

});
```